# How can I use a local variable in SELECT FROM?

Tags: sql-server

I declared a variable @Obj and assign a complete table name 'ODS..Account' to it.

```
DECLARE @Obj VARCHAR(255)
```

Then I used it in a query immediately after FROM Clause. I perceive it is just a string, unable to act as a table object. So how can I fix the code to get it works? Cheers

```
  INSERT Control.dbo.Consistency_Check
        (Table_Name              
        ,Schema_Name             
        ,Id                      
        ,Incremental_DateTime_Column       
         )
  SELECT
         @Tab 
        ,'ODS'
        ,Id
        ,SystemModstamp
  FROM
        @Obj )
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot. You probably want to use dynamic query. i.e. workout the SQL query string into a variable and exec using sp_executesql.

You may use the same variable name in the dynamic SQL but I changed it to @p_Tab for the example.

```
DECLARE @Tab int = 3 
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500) = N'@p_Tab int';  
Declare @TableName nvarchar(100) = 'ODS..Account'

/* Build the SQL string dynamicly.*/  
SET @SQLString =  N'INSERT Control.dbo.Consistency_Check
            (Table_Name              
            ,Schema_Name             
            ,Id                      
            ,Incremental_DateTime_Column       
             )
      SELECT
             @p_Tab 
            ,''ODS''
            ,Id
            ,SystemModstamp
      FROM
            '+ @TableName

EXECUTE sp_executesql   @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,
                        @p_Tab = @Tab
```

Further reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14176397)

Comment: Thank you. Adjusted as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a local variable as a *scalar* value, not as a function.  To do this, you need dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql varchar(max);

select @sql = '
INSERT Control.dbo.Consistency_Check(Table_Name, Schema_Name, Id, Incremental_DateTime_Column)
    SELECT ''@Tab'', 'ODS', Id, SystemModstamp
    FROM @Tab
';

select @sql = replace(@sql, '@tab', @tab);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It works besides a minor step to revise varchar(max) into nvarchar(max). Or otherwise it would causes error: Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Comment: It still have an error: Must declare the table variable "@Obj".

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different way of doing it with dynamic SQL:

```
    DECLARE @Obj VARCHAR(255) = 'dbo.table'

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    SET @SQL = @SQL + 
      'INSERT Control.dbo.Consistency_Check
            (Table_Name              
            ,Schema_Name             
            ,Id                      
            ,Incremental_DateTime_Column       
             )
      SELECT
             @Tab 
            ,''ODS''
            ,Id
            ,SystemModstamp
      FROM
            ' + @Obj + ''

    EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: You need to populate the value of @Tab.

Comment: @AhmedSaeed . . . I figured `@Obj` and `@Tab` are really the same thing and that was just a transcription error.